# windows service "Really Small Message Broker" OR "rsmb"

Tags: messagebroker, mqtt

http://markallanson.net/wordpress/index.php/category/rsmb/

I was trying to follow the above link for setting up mqtt as a windows service to run silently at background.
but, can't follow what the author wants to say in step one and two. 
neither there is any space for comments/questions.

I want to do this so that I don't need to input username and password every time the remote machine is started.

If you have any idea how to setup. any alternate option for not inserting the password in windows. or any suggestion please share. thnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't answer your specific question, but I can recommend the winsw "windows service wrapper" package to turn any executable into a service: http://kenai.com/projects/winsw

I can also tell you that the Windows install of the mosquitto mqtt broker ( http://mosquitto.org/) installs itself as a service automatically so this should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm quite surprised you couldn't ask the question on the original post - there is a comments form on it - http://markallanson.net/wordpress/index.php/2009/running-ibms-really-small-message-broker-on-windows/

Do you have the Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit installed? have you unzipped RSMB as the author describes? if so, the commands he lists should work for you.

As Roger says, another alternative is to use mosquitto which is similar to RSMB but is free from the license restrictions.